# How do I get the full folder path of a selected list via the Ribbon and Client Side Script?

Tags: javascript, ribbon, client-object-model

What I want to achieve is something similar to this OOB method:

```
SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList()
```

But this method only returns the GUID of the selected list. I would like to get the path, so if the user has browsed to a subfolder of the list I want to retrieve the current list/folder path.

How can this be done?